# I want to save GeoJSON polygon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, postgis, geojson, rgeo

I want to save a polygon.

This is Geojson [enter link description here](http://geojson.io/#map=15/11.0132/-74.8069http://)

```
str1 = "geojson....."
geom = RGeo::GeoJSON.decode(str1, json_parser: :json)
l = Limit.new
l.multipoligono = geom
l.save


NoMethodError: undefined methodfactory' for #RGeo::GeoJSON::FeatureCollection:0x3fc7febb7424`
```

This is my rgeo.rb

```
RGeo::ActiveRecord::SpatialFactoryStore.instance.tap do |config|
config.default = RGeo::Geos.factory_generator
config.register(RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326), geo_type: "point")
config.register(RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326), geo_type: "multi_polygon")
config.register(RGeo::Geographic.spherical_factory(srid: 4326), geo_type: "geometry_collection")

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With 110 stars, I think [this is how they do it in ruby](https://github.com/rgeo/rgeo-geojson).

```
hash = RGeo::GeoJSON.encode(feature)
hash.to_json == str2      # => true
```

That said, I wouldn't do that. I also wouldn't use Ruby. Check out PostGIS's [`ST_AsGeoJSON`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html). It returns the feature part of geojson. That is to say, cut RGeo out of the equation.